# Recommendations for a light CMS, easy editable and add-on-able?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I'm looking for a few recommendations for a light weight CMS that is easily editable by an intermediate-beginner PHP person - me. I'm not adverse to making my own, but I would much rather have such things like error handling laid out for me in advance. However, there are lots of "custom" sections to this website, like a member directory, coupon generator, form creator, etc. that it would need to be flexible and allow me to build on it. I don't need forums or other social media stuff, not even a blog.

Any hints, ideas? I can  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I personally would recommend Wordpress as it uses a pretty basic system, and the output is extremely user compatible, the plugin range is great and the support is that bit better.

The problem with this question is that its a question that does not have a direct answer, as the CMS You will use would be down to what you feel comfortable in it may not be the system anyone else would use.

Wordpress is a blogging system but can be used in many ways, There are so many big names using the system and i think this would be a great starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try WordPress / Drupal / MODx / Joomla.

98% of Content Management Systems are easy editable and add-on-able. Everybody chooses the CMS to his own taste.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something a little more lightweight:
http://grabaperch.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:- http://webdesignledger.com/tools/10-simple-and-light-weight-cms-solutions

Also have a look at this CMS: **[GetSimple](http://get-simple.info/)**

> GetSimple is an open source CMS that
>   utilizes the speed and convenience of
>   XML, a best-in-class UI and the
>   easiest learning curve of any simple
>   Content Management System out there.